# laravel 4 paginate get function return json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

if have Controller with this index function:

```
public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('web.index')
        ->with('projects', Project::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(8));
}
```

in my view there is foreach loop

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
<a href="like/{{$project->id}}" class="action like {{$liked}}">
  {{$project->likes}}
</a>
@endforeach
<div class="pagination">
  {{$projects->links()}}
</div>
```

the getLike function:

```
public function getLike($id) {
    if(Cookie::get('like_'.$id) != 'true')
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);
        $project->increment('likes');
        $cookie = Cookie::forever('like_'.$id, 'true');
        $s = array(
            'status' => 'success'
        );

        $response = Response::json($s);
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
        return $response;
    }
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'error'
    );
    return Response::json( $response );
}
```

the Ajax request:

```
$(".like").on("click", function(){
    $.get(
        $( this ).prop( 'href' ),
        {
        },
        function( data ) {

            if(data['status'] == 'error')
            {
                alert("Already Liked");
            }
            else {
                alert('Like');
            }
        },
        'json'
    );
    return false;
});
```

in the first page the getLike() function works perfectly!(im using ajax to collect the data), but when page 2 reloads( im using infinite scroll) the getLike function return blank page with the json text.
help...

Comment: Do you have enabled the error reporing and display errors? What is returned by the AJAX request (browser console)? Check the response status of your ajax request.

Comment: @Rolice yes in my app.php i set 'debug' => true, this is the Ajax request:
    $(".like").on("click", function(){
        $.get(
            $( this ).prop( 'href' ),
            {
            },
            function( data ) {

                if(data['status'] == 'error')
                {
                    alert("Already Liked");
                }
                else {
                    alert('Like');
                }
            },
            'json'
        );
        return false;
    });

Comment: And the response status?

Comment: @Rolice in the blank page with the json data i get the status is:
{"status":"success"}
the database increment work but why do i get the blank page?

Comment: Sound like a critical error then. Blank page may mean that laravel cannot handle it. As I understand the ajax works fine. Put in your controlliler file, somewhere near first lines (before the class definition) : `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'yes');` - dont forget to remove it later. Paste here if there is something is reported.

Comment: @Rolice nothing change, do you have any idea why in the first paginate(8 items) it works perfectly?

Comment: Well if no items were found your foreach will not get executed, but check why no pagination appears. You can print_r the obect to check the contents.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this approach.

1. You do a GET request to make a like. I recommend to go learn about REST principles.
2. You make a JS ajax call to PHP to set a cookie. I'm not a JS guru, but you can either store your likes in LocalStorage or set the cookie right from the JS. No need to create PHP endpoint for the same functionality.
3. If you do write PHP, use this: `return Response::json($data)->withCookie($cookie)`.

More info on Cookies in Laravel here: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies

Comment: Also, I might be wrong but using jQuery's `prop` method to get the `href` attribute isn't right either - it should be `attr`. At least according to the documentation and examples on `prop` that I can see.

Comment: @hannesvdvreken this application will be used only in serval computers sharing the same IP thats why im using cookies. how would you do Like action if not GET request?(i need also to write php to update Like counter in the database)

Comment: So you are doing something on the server to persist the state of the likes. That's good. But don't check the cookies then, check the DB. Otherwise when a user changes browser his likes will have disappeared.

Performing a POST or PUT action would be better to follow the standards of web development.